# Combine Properties loaded from <util:properties> with Properties defined from <props> element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a hibernate.properties file that holds all the hibernate properties for my application. This file is referenced by the Hibernate SessionFactoryBean from within my applicationContext.xml File:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
       ...
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <util:properties location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Now I would like to move the hibernate.dialect property to a different file in order to keep it together with the other database specific (connection) parameters.

I have tried to change the part of the sessionfactory bean like this:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <util:properties location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

However, this is not supported. I have also tried to wrap a <list></list> element around it - but this is not compatible with the expected java.util.Properties type.

How can I reference the properties file and still add the single hibernate.dialect property directly within the context file?

Alternatively, it would be ok, if I could reference the single property directly within the hibernate.properties file - but my research so far suggests that this is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<util:properties id="hibernateProperties" location="classpath:hibernate.properties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
</util:properties>
```